# How to change html text font size in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, html, fonts, uiwebview

In my application I am loading HTML String which is coming from server, the string already contain font color and font size but I need to change the color and size of the font. To replace that I have already use the followings code but its not working.

```
 UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 550, 200)];
 [webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:justify; font-size:16px;font-family:HelveticaNeue-Condensed;color:#ffff;'>%@",title] baseURL:nil];
 [webView setOpaque:NO];
 webView.delegate = self;
 [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [self addSubview:webView];
```

Is there is any other way to change it? Please suggest me the answer.

Comment: Should <div> be closed after all?

Comment: yes..i have added <div> but it is not working

Comment: And what kind of tags are used to provide the font attributes in initial string? Maybe you can replace them without adding your own <div>. Show us the example of server response, please. Not whole string, just parts connected with font.

Comment: I am getting html text from server as follows          "To show the text something, <a class=\"formfieldsubtext_link\" href=\"#\" onClick=\"window.open('gb_NY_term.jsp','nyPopup','width=580,height=400,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,resizable=no')\">click here.</a>
\n"

Comment: @SteveGear your problem is solved or not? if yes then plz accept answer or upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I used following code

```
      NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><body bgcolor=#EAEAEA><font face='Myriad Pro' size='3'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=5.0; user-scalable=YES'/>";///You can set your colour using font tag
      NSString *endHtml=@"</font></body></html>";
      NSString *strDes=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",embedHTML,videoShareObject.strDescription,endHtml];
      [self.webViewObj loadHTMLString:strDes baseURL:nil];
      NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;", fontSizeSlider.value]; //I used the Sliderbar, You can set your font size.
      [webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:string];
```

Comment: i am getting two html texts with different font sizes and different colours from server... Now i want to change those two with same font size and colour.....  I have used this code also ...but still it is not working

Comment: you can concatenate your both string In strDes variable.

Comment: How do i know.. it is in loop... some times come one string,two strings and all....

Comment: put it to for loop : [StringVariable stringByAppendingString:@"Your html String"]; and after for loop  strDes=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",embedHTML,StringVariable,endHtml]